# Rest Document Service

Tags: json, rest, xpages, document, xpages-extlib

I have following code where in I want to display data from a Rest Doc Service into Dojo Data Grid. Output of Rest service is fine but Datagrid siplay displays the column titles and nothing else.
Here is my code:

```
<xp:panel>
        <xe:restService id="restService1" pathInfo="docAccReq1"
            rendered="true" state="true">
            <xe:this.service>
                <xe:documentJsonService
                    contentType="application/json" systemItems="63" var="docAcc"
                    documentUnid="80EFAE936EA978A480257CE4002DBC67">
                    <xe:this.items>
                        <xe:restDocumentItem itemName="Name"
                            name="Name">
                        </xe:restDocumentItem>
                        <xe:restDocumentItem
                            itemName="ACCESSREQUESTER" name="ACCESSREQUESTER">
                        </xe:restDocumentItem>
                        <xe:restDocumentItem
                            itemName="ACCESSREQUESTEDDATE" name="ACCESSREQUESTEDDATE">
                        </xe:restDocumentItem>
                    </xe:this.items>
                </xe:documentJsonService>
            </xe:this.service>
        </xe:restService>

        <xe:djxDataGrid id="djxDataGrid1"
            storeComponentId="restService1" store="docStore">
            <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
                <xp:dojoAttribute name="autoWidth" value="true"></xp:dojoAttribute>
            </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
            <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn1"
                field="Name">
            </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
            <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn2"
                field="ACCESSREQUESTER">
            </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
            <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn3"
                field="ACCESSREQUESTEDDATE">
            </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
        </xe:djxDataGrid>

        <xe:firebugLite id="firebugLite1"></xe:firebugLite>
</xp:panel>
<xp:panel>
    <xc:ccDebugToolbar defaultCollapsed="true"
        collapseTo="left"></xc:ccDebugToolbar>
</xp:panel>
```

Comment: here is the output of rest service:{"@unid":"80EFAE936EA978A480257CE4002DBC67","@noteid":"12C7A","@created":{"data":"2014-05-26T08:19:33Z","type":"datetime"},"@modified":{"data":"2014-05-26T11:13:39Z","type":"datetime"},"@authors":["CN=Arun Agnihotri\/O=XYZ"],"Name":"Arun","ACCESSREQUESTER":"Arun Agnihotri","ACCESSREQUESTEDDATE":{"data":"2014-05-26T08:19:31Z","type":"datetime"}}

Comment: Shouldn't you use "viewJsonService" instead to get documents from a view and not just one certain document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The REST service should deliver a data *array*. This is what `xe:djxDataGrid` expects as it is a data grid control which shows data in multiple rows in a table.

The common way is to use the REST service `viewJsonService`. Define all columns you want to see in data grid in a view. You connect the view to REST service with parameter "viewName" and with `defaultColumns="true"` you make sure that *all* columns get delivered.

Your REST service definition would look like this then:

```
<xe:restService
    id="restService1"
    pathInfo="docAccReq1">
    <xe:this.service>
        <xe:viewJsonService
            viewName="AccessRequests"
            defaultColumns="true" />
    </xe:this.service>
</xe:restService>
```

The REST service delivers JSON data as an array:

```
[
  {
      "@entryid":"1-80EFAE936EA978A480257CE4002DBC67",
      "@unid":"80EFAE936EA978A480257CE4002DBC67",
      "@noteid":"12C7A",
      "@position":"1",
      "@read":true,
      "@siblings":200,
      "@form":"access",
      "Name":"Arun",
      "ACCESSREQUESTER":"Arun Agnihotri",
      "ACCESSREQUESTEDDATE":"2014-05-26T08:19:31Z"
  },
  {
      ...
  },
  ...
]
```

The values "@position" and "@siblings" are important for Dojo Data Grid. They tell how many entries are in view and which position is the current data entry on. This allows to show a right sized vertical scroll bar at the right vertical position.

The Rest service `documentJsonService` you used delivers only one single JSON object (not an array) and doesn't provide those additional information.